# How to use LINQ to find if any Value in a ResultPropertyCollection contains a certain substring?

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory

How to use LINQ to find if any Value in a ResultPropertyCollection contains a certain substring?

Background: After a renaming of my employer firm, I want to check whether all users have a proper new email alias, which are listed in Active Directory as proxyAddresses.
Directly accessing single values inside the ResultPropertyCollection works just fine, like so:

```
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(mySearchRoot, myFilter, myPropertiesList);
myResults = mySearcher.FindAll();

var query = from SearchResult myResult in myResults
    where (myResult.Properties["proxyAddresses"][0].ToString().Contains ("WeNeedThis.com"))
    select myResult;
```

But I fail at searching over all values inside the collection. I cant seem to find out what the proper type for the range variable is:

```
where (from WhatType? myAddress in myResult.Properties["proxyAddresses"] 
    where (myAddress.Contains("WeNeedThis.com"))    
    select myAddress)
```

How can I set up the where clause so it finds any occurence of the search string in any Value of proxyAddresses?

Answer: Turns out this is the correct where clause:

```
   where ( ( from String myAddress in myResult.Properties["proxyAddresses"]
       where myAddress.Contains("WeNeedThis.com") 
       select myAddress).ToList().Count == 0)
```

There were two mistakes intertwined: The outer where clause needs a boolean result from the result of the inner select, which is achieved by .ToList().Count == 0. 
The type of the range variable is indeed String = myResult.Properties["proxyAddresses"][0].GetType(), although the Collection has no direct String members. I misinterpreted the resulting compiler error.

Comment: Do you need to retrieve these or just find out if any exist?

Comment: I need to check if one of them contains a certain substring.

Comment: That's doesn't really answer the question - do you need to do something with the address or just confirm that there is an address with this substring?

Comment: Just confirming would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you're looking for I think is [ResultPropertyValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.resultpropertyvaluecollection.aspx).

But, can't you omit the type and use type inference?

```
from myAddress in myResult.Properties["proxyAddresses"]
```

Also instead of using `IndexOf(str) > 0` as your predicate, you could use `Contains(str)`.

Comment: Omittig the type leads to a compiler error: Error 3 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'myAddress'.

Comment: Aaah. Doesn't implement `IQueryable`? But it is an `IDictionary`. Try wapping the `.AsQueryable()` extension method on the end of that line.

Comment: It does implement IQueryable, but doesnt make the type inference. The working statement required an explicit type too. I tried it as String but that didnt work either.

Comment: hmm... well did you try `ResultPropertyValueCollection`?

Comment: Accepted this answer, because it led me in the right direction, and I indeed am using .Contains() now.

Comment: An actual example of what you finally ended up with would be super helpful!  ;D (Just saying that you're using .Contains() now doesn't help those of us with weak extrapolation skills.)

Answer (score 1):

The System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection PropertyNames is from type Hashtable+Keycollection. I would cast it and check it if it exist, then get the value out of it:

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(mySearchRoot, myFilter, myPropertiesList);
System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection myResults = mySearcher.FindAll();
foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult result in myResults)
{
   var propertyNames = result.Properties.PropertyNames.Cast<String>().ToList<String>();
   if (!propertyNames.Contains("proxyaddresses")) 
   {
      // This property does not exist. Abort.
      continue;
   }
   List<string> proxyAddresses = result.Properties["proxyaddresses"].Cast<String>().ToList();
   // Do something with proxyAddresses
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use something like this:

```
var query =
    from myAddress in
        (myResult.Properties["proxyAddresses"] as IEnumerable).OfType<string>()
    where myAddress
        .ToLowerInvariant()
        .Contains("WeNeedThis.com".ToLowerInvariant())
    select myAddress ;
```

Does this help?

Comment: This leads to an error on the select:  Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'bool'... I had this with the working statement before I added the correct type on the range variable.

Comment: @posipiet - Just add a `.Any()` to see if the query produced a value - that will turn it into a `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(mySearchRoot, myFilter, myPropertiesList);
myResults = mySearcher.FindAll();

var query = myResults.Where(res =>res.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["proxyAddresses"].Cast<string>().Any(addr => addr.Contains("WeNeedThis.com")));
```